# How to make Spring Boot fail fast when did not found database configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm running a Spring Boot application.

When there's no application.properties file in standard config paths it is not loaded and default configuration seems to be loaded.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver:...
```

Because of that, Spring Boot creates empty database with scheme without data which leads to empty program output.

How can one prevent Spring Boot from loading database default configuration?

Comment: default configuration is only loaded if you have an embedded database in your application; It's not failing at all so I am not sure I understand what you expect.

Comment: An `application.properties` isn't required so no it will not fail and then do its best to determine what to configure. If it doesn't fail you probably have an embedded database like H2, HSQLDB on your classpath. Remove those dependencies and also make sure that you don't have an `application.properties` inside your application as well because that will also be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something as follows `exclude` in `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations to exclude Datasource default configuration. [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html#using-boot-disabling-specific-auto-configuration)

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

I don't know if there is any provision to make the app fail fast.

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop Spring-Boot from autoconfiguring certain features for you, **you need to explicitly exclude** the corresponding class from the auto-configuration config:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

*Note: using this annotation you are taking back the responsibility from Spring to setup things for you, so you need to configure your DB properly from now on.*